# Solving $\sin(x) = 0.65$ on a given interval

Tags: trigonometry

From Khan Academy, Solving Sinusoidal Equations Practice:

[image: Here is the original question]

Here 13.28 is correct but I'm not sure why.

Because 13.28 - (3.1415) = 0.72 
While arcsin(0.65) = 0.71

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculators???

Comment: The periodicity of the $\sin$ function is $2\pi$, not $\pi$.

Comment: $\sin (x - \pi) = - \sin x \ne \sin x$.  So either $13.28 - 2k*(3.1415) = .71$ (which is does for $k=2$ or $(2k+1)\pi - 13.28 = .71$ (which is doesn't).  That $13.28 - 3.1415 = .72  .... what?  no it ... doesn't.

Comment: .... 13.28 is *not* the correct answer.  It is *one* of the *three* correct answer.  It does say check *all* that apply.

Comment: to expand on @Myridium's comment:  The periodicity of sin is $2\pi$ so if $x$ is solution so will $x + 2k\pi$.  The other thing to note is $\sin(\pi - x)=\sin x$. So if $x$ is solution so will $2k\pi + x$ and $(2k+1)\pi - x$.  Those will be the only solutions because $\sin x$ is increasing or decreasing between multiples of $\pi$ and can not take the same value twice between multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin x = m$ will have an infinite number of solutions.

There will be one solution in each interval $[2k\pi - \frac {\pi}2 , 2k\pi + \frac {\pi}2]$ and will be one solution in each interval $[2k\pi + \frac{\pi}2,3k\pi + \frac {\pi}2=4k\pi - \frac {\pi}2]$

The $\arcsin m$ will be only one of the solutions; the solution in $[ - \frac {\pi}2 ,  \frac {\pi}2]$.

The solution in $[2k\pi - \frac {\pi}2 , 2k\pi + \frac {\pi}2]$ will be $\arcsin m + 2k\pi$.  The solution in $[2k\pi + \frac{\pi}2,3k\pi + \frac {\pi}2]$ will be $3k\pi - \arcsin m$.

The big interval $[\frac {3\pi}2 , \frac {9\pi}2] = [2\pi - \frac {\pi}2, 4\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}] = [2\pi - \frac {\pi}2, 4\pi + \frac{\pi}2]\cup [2\pi + \frac {\pi}2, 3\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}]\cup [4\pi - \frac {\pi}2, 4\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}] $ contains three such intervals, so there will be $3$ solutions.

They will be $2\pi + \arcsin .65$, $3\pi - \arcsin.65$, and $4\pi + \arcsin .65$.

Or in other words $2*3.14 + .71, 3*3.14 - .71, 4*3.14 + .71$ or $6.99,8.71,$ and $13.28$.

Anyway, it doesn't follow that if $\sin x = k$ then $x - \pi = \arcsin k$.  That will ... never happen.  $\sin (x - \pi) = - \sin x$ so $x - \pi = -\arcsin k$ *might* happen if $x \in [\pi, \frac {3\pi}2]$ but $x - \pi \ne \arcsin k$.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER** (credit to fleablood, who has a better answer than I do!)

The principal value (i.e. between $0 < x < \pi/2$) of $\sin (x) = 0.65$ is $0.71$.

To find the angle within $3 \pi/2 < x < 9\pi/2$, note that we will have three other angles that are coterminal with $0.71$, as we will sweep the unit circle three times...they are $2 \pi + 0.71$, $3 \pi - 0.71$ and $4 \pi + 0.71$.

$2 \pi + 0.71 \approx 6.99$ and $3 \pi - 0.71 \approx 8.71$ is within the interval and are coterminal, but not close to the larger interval of $9 \pi/2$.

The angle we want is thus $4\pi$ plus the principal value $0.71$, which is approximately $13.28.$

Comment: should note that $3\pi 2 --- 9\pi 2$ spans a distance of $3\pi$.  This allows for $3$ possible solutions of which 13.28 is only one.

Comment: Thanks, fleablood...I wasn't quite sure how to describe how I got the answer, but I will correct mine and give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\arcsin(0.65) \approx 0.7076$$
$$0.7076 + 4\pi \approx 13.28$$
$$\frac{3 \pi}{2} < 13.28 < \frac{9 \pi}{2}$$